# Getting Karate testing framework to work with Windows WSL2

Tags: karate, wsl-2

Simple question. Try as I may I cannot find any resources discussing this and when I attempt to get it to work it does not. Spent a few days on it now.

Went to ask this question on the Karate github page and it sent me here...

I tried using Karate with IntelliJ and WSL2 and it does not work.

Comment: that's never come up as a question before so I'm intrigued. can you explain more, what do you mean by "it does not work" (feel free to edit your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )  in the meantime, see if you can install docker, that will get you going: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/docker/README.md